# Jupyter Notebook "Proceed (Y/n)?" Keyboard Input?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, keyboard, user-input

I mainly write code via Jupyter Notebook. It is for example very convenient to install packages via Jupyter Notebook with `pip install package_name`, if I need some. 
Today I wanted to uninstall a package fast in my workflow via `pip uninstall package_name` and I realised I couldn't pass a keyboard input. 
*Proceed (Y/n)?* 
I dont' have a problem with uninstalling a package. I just want to know, if there is a convenient way of doing everything in Jupyter Notebook? I couldn't find a clear and straightforward solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `pip uninstall package_name -y`

Answer (score 0):

If you work on a Jupyter Notebook in **VS Code** (*e.g., ".ipynb" file*):

1. You can run your Code in your Notebook as you used to.
2. Open a "New Terminal" window and enter your requested Input there, while still running everything on the Jupyter Notebook.

For just **Jupyter Notebook** I still don't have an awnser, but I hope this maybe helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```py
my_package_name = input() # read your keyboard input
!pip uninstall {my_package_name} # use it as argument
```

Comment: If it is being run inside a notebook, you should be suggesting use of `%pip` and no longer an exclamation point in conjunction with pip or conda. Modern magics were added to avoid THE MANY ISSUES the use if the exclamation point can cause because it doesn't necessarily run in the environment backing the current notebook. Please see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about the modern `%pip` and `%conda` magic commands.